# Floating window in main window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF window application.

An `addWindow()` method creates another window and place it next to main window (window position and size is configured in settings). That caused me to add another monitor in order to view the added window.

How can I add that second window to same screen (as a small floating window at top right corner, etc) and allow user to switch between the views ?

Current method implementation:

```
private void addWindow()
{
   this.myScreen = new Project.myMonitorWindow();
   this.myScreen.init();
   this.myScreen.Show();
}
```

Comment: What does `Project.myMonitorWindows.init()` do?

Comment: initiate the myMonitorWindow, which inherit the Window class @CodingFeles

Comment: You need to describe the behavior and look of the window more thoroughly. It's not clear that kind of window do you want.  As you described it now, any default window fits well.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution is to use a [popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx) (example at the bottom in the linked page). You can make it act like a regular window, and you can position it relative to an element from the calling window. Not sure what you mean by "switching between the views", but it also has a parameter called StaysOpen (bool), and if StaysOpen = false, that means it will close when you click outside the popup's boundaries.